# what is wrong in my code for calculate parameters bivariate distribution?

Tags: distributions, parameters

data is i,j as x, y  as in pic

[image]

```
 i = {42, 180, 35, 392, 63, 230, 112, 281, 42, 28, 42, 120, 148, 16, 310, 28, 68, 336, 21.5, 50, 19, 30, 12, 120, 140, 170, 17, 115, 31, 21, 52, 164, 225, 225, 151, 60, 200, 46, 210, 14};
 j = {4.5, 27, 19, 30.4, 28, 50, 7, 30, 3.5, 50, 6, 10.4, 20, 3.9, 41, 9, 7.6, 46, 2.6, 24, 3.2, 2, 5, 6.5, 12, 20.2, 13, 27, 18, 4.7, 9.8, 29, 7, 6, 20, 45, 7.5, 2.3, 24, 3};
```

[image]

Such that
θ
=( α ,
λ 1,
λ 2,a,b), MLEs are gotten by maximizing equation

It cannot be acquired explicitly. We want to solve ﬁve nonlinear equations to compute MLEs, then we must use real data for get the values of the unknown parameters.

i write code as this

```
I1 = Total[
   log[1 \[Minus] \[Alpha] (1 \[Minus] e \[Minus] \[Lambda]1 (i \[Minus] a)) (1 \[Minus] e \[Minus] \[Lambda]2 (j \[Minus] b))]];


I2 = (\[Alpha] \[Minus] 2) Total[
log[1 \[Minus] (1 \[Minus] 
      e \[Minus] \[Lambda]1 (i \[Minus] a)) (1 \[Minus] 
      e \[Minus] \[Lambda]2 (j \[Minus] b))]];


Maxlik = nlog[\[Alpha]\[Lambda]1\[Lambda]2] \[Minus] \[Lambda]1Sum[(i \
\[Minus] a), {i, {42, 180, 35, 392, 63, 230, 112, 281, 42, 28, 42, 
        120, 148, 16, 310, 28, 68, 336, 21.5, 50, 19, 30, 12, 120, 
        140, 170, 17, 115, 31, 21, 52, 164, 225, 225, 151, 60, 200, 
        46, 210, 14}}] \[Minus] \[Lambda]2Sum[(j \[Minus] 
       b), {j, {4.5, 27, 19, 30.4, 28, 50, 7, 30, 3.5, 50, 6, 10.4, 
       20, 3.9, 41, 9, 7.6, 46, 2.6, 24, 3.2, 2, 5, 6.5, 12, 20.2, 13,
        27, 18, 4.7, 9.8, 29, 7, 6, 20, 45, 7.5, 2.3, 24, 3}}] + I1 + 
   I2;


Dbalfa = D[Maxlik, \[Alpha]];
Dblambda1 = D[Maxlik, \[Lambda]1];
Dblambda2 = D[Maxlik, \[Lambda]2];
Dba = D[Maxlik, a];
Dbb = D[Maxlik, b];


FindRoot[{Dbalfa == 0, Dblambda1 == 0, Dblambda2 == 0, Dba == 0, Dbb == 0}, {{\[Alpha], .047}, {\[Lambda]1, .1}, {\[Lambda]2, .3}, \{a, 12}, {b, 10}}]
```

i get this no result
[image]

Comment: Mathematica is violently case sensitive. So it is `Log` and not `log` and it is `E` and not `e` (unless you have desktop published Euler's constant.) And, unless you have some missing code, Your `Total` syntax is wrong. `n` hasn't been given any value. Your `i` in your `I1` and `I2` doesn't seem to have a value. Just as an experiment, instead of `FindRoot` just display `{Dbalfa==0,Dblambda1==0,Dblambda2==0,Dba==0,Dbb==0}` and look at it and see all the variables that don't have values. Put `*` inside `nlog` and inside `\[Lambda]1Sum` and inside `\[Lambda]2Sum` Please fix all those now. THanks

Comment: You need to post code without syntax errors.  `log` should be `Log`, `nlog[\[Alpha]\[Lambda]1\[Lambda]2]` should be `n Log[\[Alpha] \[Lambda]1 \[Lambda]2]`, etc.  You've had other questions with this same issue.

Comment: Would you post a link to the reference (article or book) for Table 1 and the log of the likelihood?

Comment: It's  Truncated Bivariate Kumaraswamy Exponential
Distribution            http://dx.doi.org/10.18576/jsap/110208

Comment: Thank you!  That explains a lot.  For those considering helping with this question, the *Mathematica* code is given in the appendix of the journal article.  But that appendix is not formatted properly and results in what you see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Mathematica* code above is from the appendix of https://www.naturalspublishing.com/files/published/p6x2vhc2x96687.pdf but unfortunately it is not formatted properly to import directly into *Mathematica*.

I have made changes in the code for two reasons:  (1) To fix formatting errors and (2) because the maximum likelihood estimates do not result in all of the derivatives of the log of the likelihood being zero.

Issue (2) is because the maximum likelihood estimates of parameters $a$ and $b$ are the respective minimums of the datasets:  `Min[i]` and `Min[j]`.  In such cases the derivatives of the log of the likelihood won't be zero for those parameters.

Below is what I think is the appropriate code using `FindMaximum` rather than `FindRoot`.

```
(* Data *)
i = {42, 180, 35, 392, 63, 230, 112, 281, 42, 28, 42, 120, 148, 16, 
   310, 28, 68, 336, 21.5, 50, 19, 30, 12, 120, 140, 170, 17, 115, 31,
    21, 52, 164, 225, 225, 151, 60, 200, 46, 210, 14};
j = {4.5, 27, 19, 30.4, 28, 50, 7, 30, 3.5, 50, 6, 10.4, 20, 3.9, 41, 
   9, 7.6, 46, 2.6, 24, 3.2, 2, 5, 6.5, 12, 20.2, 13, 27, 18, 4.7, 
   9.8, 29, 7, 6, 20, 45, 7.5, 2.3, 24, 3};
n = Length[i];

(* Construct log of the likelihood *)
I1 = Total[Log[1 - α (1 - Exp[-λ1 (i - a)]) (1 - Exp[-λ2 (j - b)])]];
I2 = (α - 2) Total[Log[1 - (1 - Exp[-λ1 (i - a)]) (1 - Exp[-λ2 (j - b)])]];
logL = n Log[α λ1 λ2] - λ1 Total[i - a] - λ2 Total[j - b] + I1 + I2;

(* Maximum likelihood estimates *)
mle = FindMaximum[{logL /. a -> Min[i] /. b -> Min[j], {λ1 > 0, λ2 > 0}},
  {{α, .047}, {λ1, .1}, {λ2, .3}}]
(* {-366.874, {α -> 0.549173, λ1 -> 0.0173524, λ2 -> 0.123608}} *)
```